# What does a beam with no notes signify? (semiquaver beam in my case)

Tags: beaming

I have the below measure showing what appears a semiquaver beam for 1 beat without notes in the middle of the bar. What does this mean?

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks it certainly looks like that now that you mention it I had just never seen it so .... long!

Comment: It's because of the 16th notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd wager that it's a tremolo in the right hand, between the triad and the single note. But I don't know this particular piece, etc., so I can't be sure.

Comment: Its the 3rd from last bar of Pearl Fishers from Jeffrey Howard's arrangement. Gosh I have never seen a tremolo this stretched out!